# I want to understand how the Paperclip gem handles s3 down time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

I hope that this question does not have an extremely simple answer that I have completely overlooked.

My question is how does the paperclip gem handle s3 down time?  What is the flow if a user uploads an asset and s3 is not responding due to it becoming unavailable.  The specifics; I am using paperclip 2.7 gem with rails 3.  I tried looking through the documentation and tests but could not see that this was being handled.  If s3 downtime is not being handled by the paperclip gem what is the best practice for me to handle it in my model.  Ideally I don't want a save to occur and an error to be transmitted to the user.

How have others handled this?

Any insight into this will be helpful,

Slan

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for paperclip? Whenever I'm slightly confused as to what the gem is doing, I just break it open and dig around.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it will raise an exception, because uploads are synchronous by default. That's a problem you'll have to handle by yourself.

One solution would be to upload in background with [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for instance.

I made a gist to hook paperclip file upload [here](https://gist.github.com/basgys/5494162) (it's not production ready)